# Create Pedometer using PhoneGap

Tags: android, iphone, cordova, phonegap-plugins, accelerator

i want to create an application of Pedometer using PhoneGap which has two main fetures

*i want to use PhoneGap for Android and Iphone*

> 1) User Accelerator Api to support counting of steps
>
> 2) Play music in background using MP3 player in background.

As i am new to PhoneGap ,

```
i want to know that above features are possible to implement using PhoneGap APIs?

                                    OR 
Better to choose Native App ?
```

*if this  questions sounds unreal then please feel free to ask question rather then voting for close.*

Comment: down voters and close voters, have a courtesy to give a reason for the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out the api and see if wha features u need are supported
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.5.0/index.html

if some native api is not supported and u need it then u would have to write plugins for each platform

Answer (score 0):

http://phonegap.com/about/features :)

Comment: Welcome to SO!  When trying to answer questions, try to summarize relevant points in addition to providing a link!